# One big and wide table or many not so big for statistics data

Tags: postgresql, database-design, analytics

I'm writing simplest analytics system for my company. I have about 100 different event types that should be collected per tens of projects. We are not interested in cross-project analytic requests but events have similar types through all projects. I use PostgreSQL as primary storage for this system. Now I should decide which architecture is more preferable.

**First architecture** is *one very big table* (in terms of rows count) per project that contains data for all types of events. It will be about 20 or more columns many of them will be nullable. May be it will be used partitioning to split this table by event type but table still be so wide.

**Second one architecture** is *a lot of tables* (fairly big in terms of rows count but not so wide) with one table per event type.

I going to retrieve analytic data from this tables using different join queries (self join in case of first architecture). Which one is more preferable and where are pitfalls of them?

**UPD**. All events have about 10 common attributes. And remain attributes are varied from one event type to another.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I've had similar situations. With postgres you have a bunch of options.
Depending on how your data is input into the system (all at once/ a little at a time) and the volume of your data per project (hundreds of data points vs millions of data points)  and the querying pattern (IE, querying after the data is all in, querying nightly, or reports running constantly throughout), there are many options. One other factor will be IF new project types (with new data point types) are likely to crop up.

First, in your "first architecture" the first question that comes up for me is: Are all the "data points" the same data type (or at least very similar). Are some text and others numeric? Are some numeric and others floats? If so, you're likely to run into issues with rolling up your data without either building a column or a table for every data type.
If all your data is the same datatype, then the first architecture you mentioned might work really well.

The second architecture you mentioned is OK especially if you don't predict having a bunch of new project types coming down the pike anytime soon, otherwise, you'll be constantly modifying the DB, which I prefer to avoid when unnecessary.

A third architecture that you didn't mention is to have a combination of 1 and 2. Basically have 1 table to hold the 10 common attributes and use either 1 or 2 to hold the additional attributes. This would have an advantage, especially if the additional data wasn't that frequently used, or was non-numeric.

Lastly, you could use one of PostgreSQLs "document store" type datatypes. You could store this information in arrays, hstores, or json. Now, this will be fairly inefficient if you're doing a ton of aggregate functions as you might be left calculating the aggregates outside of Pgsql, or at a minimum, running an inefficient query. You could store the 10 common fields in normal fields, and the additional ones as hstore or json.

I didn't ask you, but it'd be nice to know that if each event within a project had more than 1 data point (IE are you logging changes, or just updating data).If your overall table has less than 100,000 rows, it's likely just going to be best to focus on what's easier to maintain and program rather than performance, as small amounts of data are pretty quick regardless of how they're stored.